# Python sieve prime numbers

Tags: python, sieve

I am trying to get the sum of all prime numbers using a sieve on Python 2.7.  However when I run the program I only wind up with 0 everytime.
I have no idea why this is happening.

```
import math,time

start=time.clock()

def primesieve(limit):
  final=0
  a=[True]*limit
  a[0]=a[1]=False
  for i,isprime in enumerate(a):
    if isprime:
      for n in xrange(i,limit,i):
        a[n]=False
  for i in xrange(limit):
    if a[i]:
        final=final+i
  return final

print primesieve(2000000)

elapsed=time.clock()-start

print elapsed
```

Comment: Use `timeit` to time code, rather than `time.clock()`

Comment: @Volatility i meant the function is returning 0 no matter what. il change it using timeit though

Comment: It was meant as a general tip, not a solution to the problem. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

```
for n in xrange(i,limit,i):
    a[n]=False
```

It should be:

```
for n in xrange(2*i,limit,i):
    a[n]=False
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
for n in xrange(i*i,limit, 2*i): #assuming you already cleared even numbers
    a[n]=False
```

Because otherwise you end up setting `i` as non-prime, when it actually is a prime.
(The sieve should mark all multiples of `i` as non-primes, except `i` itself!)

---

Note that you are iterating over all the numbers, up to `limit`, but you can safely stopped after reaching `sqrt(limit)`:

```
import itertools as it

def primesieve(limit):
    a = [True] * limit
    a[0] = a[1] = False
    sqrt_limit = int(limit**0.5) + 1
    predicate = lambda x: x[0] <= sqrt_limit
    for i, isprime in it.takewhile(predicate, enumerate(a)):
        if isprime:
            for n in xrange(i*i, limit, i):
                a[n] = False
    return sum(i for i,n in enumerate(a) if n)
```

The `takewhile` function will stop the iteration right after reaching the square root of `limit`. The `i*i` wont give errors since it will always be smaller than `limit`.

On my machine it is about twice as fast as iterating over all the numbers.

Comment: thanks a lot. its working but using i squared gives the error 'Python int too large to convert to C long'

Comment: That's because you are iterating over all the numbers. You could stop the iterations when the index `i` is bigger than `sqrt(limit)`, this would both prevent the error and make the code faster.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this related topic: 
[Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python/18944432#18944432)
Fastest sieve below 8 * 10^8 is rwh_prime1 coded by @Robert William Hanks

```
'''Robert William Hanks 2010'''
def primes1(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    sieve = [True] * (n/2)
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i/2]:
            sieve[i*i/2::i] = [False] * ((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [2*i+1 for i in xrange(1,n/2) if sieve[i]]
```